# Receiving error when executitng code in Databricks / Spark DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

When running the following command I get the error

I am running the code on Databricks Platform, but the code is written using Pandas

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Can someone let me know if the error is related to spark / databricks platform not supporting the code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def matchSchema(df):
    df['active'] = df['active'].astype('boolean')
    df['price'] = df['counts']/100
    df.drop('counts', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df,df.head(3)

(dataset, sample) =  matchSchema(df)

print(dataset)
print(sample)
```

The error is:

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bool is used instead of boolean as a dtype...

```
df['active'] = df['active'].astype('bool')
```